# Site-to-site VPN on Azure

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn

I have a Virtual Network created on Azure and i need to establish a Site-to-site VPN connection with it.

I found this [Article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB1oS.jpg), but it only describes creating a VPN connection at a time of Virutual network creation, and I need it for a already created network.

I looked for a **Configure a site-to-site VPN** checkbox for that network, but couldn't find it.

***Please advice how to create that site-to-site VPN for a already created virtual network, and why it won't let me to do that now.***

I also have to mention that my Gateway Type is Dynamic Routing. I have Cisco ASA 5525, so as far as I understood it has to be Static.

Also on a Dashboard where it has to show a VPN status on  Client side it's saying "A root certificate has not been uploaded."

[image]

Comment: Should this be moved to networking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an option for site-to-site VPN does not show up follow these steps to troubleshoot:

1. Have you created a point-to-site VPN before? If yes, please delete the VPN gateway.
2. In addition, please define a local network by clicking New in the manament portal and selecting Network Service>Virtual Network>Add local network.
3. Then please uncheck the point-to-site connectivity and check the site-to-site connectivity. After that, recreate a static VPN gateway.